# 80s movie about a genius boy who invents a force field to deflect football balls

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a movie about a boy who is the typical little genius. I watched it in Italy in the early 80s.

The things I remember about the protagonist:

- his chamber was full of electrical devices
- he wore glasses and seemed to be about 12-13 years old and was a bit socially awkward
- at one point, he accepts to play soccer with some kids; after realizing he wasn't good at the game, he invented a kind of force field, so that the ball bounced against it without scoring a goal (he was playing as goalkeeper, and stayed motionless all the time keeping his hands in front of himself)
- the main plotline is about this boy using his inventions to defeat a group of burglars who wanted to steal something that was in his house.

The movie was targeted at younger audiences and didn't look like a big budget movie. It also seemed European rather than American.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Blinker's Spy Spotter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0421754/).

> BLINKER’S SPY SPOTTER (1972) Bring on the first of many silly titles. Blinker (DAVID SPOONER) is the son of a professor who’s just invented the usual “top-secret device”. **He’s also goalie for the local kid’s football team, and himself invents a “goal repeller” which works, much to the chagrin of symbolically-named rival team The Masons.** Then he invents a radar (about fifty years after Albert Taylor did much the same thing, but details, details) and discovers – shock! Some nasty-but-bungling crooks are after the top secret effort! So the team set out to foil them. As you might expect.

Comment: Yes, I'm almost sure this is the movie I watched as kid! Thanks a lot!!!